# What to use for a UI app running on Synology

Tags: synology

I need write an app to synology. As far as I saw Synology UI apps are base on html/js.

Does anyone knows if is it possible to run other type of UI app? E.g. qt/qml, but not web assembly because the app needs to communicate with a daemon over unix socket(and as far as i saw webasm/emscript works with web sockets instead of unix sockets).

Thanks